# Introduction to CodeIgniter and ExpressionEngine

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

I'm looking for an introduction in creating application using CodeIgniter and Integrating it to ExpressionEngine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeffrey Way's tutorials on nettuts are really good:
http://net.tutsplus.com/videos/screencasts/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/

Answer (score 1):

You might find this this tutorial helpful for migrating a Codeigniter app to ExpressionEngine:

http://jadb.wordpress.com/2011/11/15/migrate-codeigniter-app-to-expressionengine/

(this assumes you know a little something about both CI and EE)